# Lightbox displays garbage characters instead of image

Tags: php, jquery, character-encoding, gd, lightbox

I have installed a lightbox script in my website. When lightbox pops up, but there are garbage characters displaying instead of the large version of the image:

```
����JFIF��;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v62), quality = 90 ��C     ��C    ����"�� ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz�������������������
```

What is this? It looks like it's relevant to the image file but I don't understand what causes this issue... Any suggestions?

Edit: [Here's the whole code of the image](http://www.sendspace.com/file/gbpbcc).

Comment: Those "garbage characters" are actually the string representation of the binary data in the JPEG image file.

Comment: I see... but why isn't the image displayed normally?

Comment: How long is a piece of string? I can't tell without seeing it. Same goes for your problem - we need to see the code.

Comment: I added a link to a text file that contains the image code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in the php file where you are creating the image dynamically using GD liabrary write following code.

```
header("content-type:image/jpg");
```

OR if it is a png image then

```
header("content-type:image/png");
```

From the code it seems to be a jpg file. But you should know the format.

Basically it is problem in php file rather than the lightbox.

Answer (score 1):

Just had this after I was doing some random tasks. Couldn't see why images were displaying fine until I attempted to load them in lightbox, turns out the html attributes had non-displaying characters on the end of the filename.

```
<a href="image1.jpg"><img src="image1.jpg" /></a>
```

had become:

```
<a href="image1.jpg
"><img src="image1.jpg
" /></a>
```

Trimming the filenames (in my case with PHP's trim() function) to remove these erroneous characters made it behave correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the colorbox js file as the following:

```js
photoRegex: /\.(gif|jfif|png|jp(e|g|eg)|bmp|ico|webp|jxr|svg)((#|\?).*)?$/i,
```