# eModal displays binary data rather image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, modal-dialog

I have an eModal (http://saribe.github.io/eModal) dialog box in which I would like to display an image. Unfortunately, when I run `eModal.ajax('/path/to/image.jpg','View Image');` I see my modal full of binary data rather than the image as I would expect. I have verified that /path/to/image.jpg is valid and loads on its own just fine. Any ideas? Am I calling eModal.ajax() in the wrong way or something?

edit: so I also tried using an iframe to load the image as eModal is supposed to allow for easy handling of iframes. same issue. the strange thing is that if I open the page that sets up the iframe in a separate browser tab (not an eModal window), it displays my image fine. it's only when loading it within the eModal dialog box that it shows the binary data for some odd reason.

second edit: I also tried making an auxiliary PHP script called getfile.php which simply outputs an image to the browser while making sure to send to send the correct content-type. Below is my code for getfile.php, which works fine, except in the modal. same issue. also, I found the following question which seems to raise the same issue, but none of the solutions suggested there work for me: [Lightbox displays garbage characters instead of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10683700/lightbox-displays-garbage-characters-instead-of-image)

```
<?php
$file = $_REQUEST['img'];


if (file_exists($file))
{
    $size = getimagesize($file);

    $fp = fopen($file, 'rb');

    if ($size and $fp)
    {
        header('Content-Type: '.$size['mime']);
        header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));

        fpassthru($fp);

        exit;
    }
}

?>
```

attached is a screenshot showing what it shows instead of the image: [eModal showing binary data instead of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du9RV.jpg)